# multi page form in codeigniter and save data in database after each step validation

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, multi-step

i m building multi page form ,I want each section to validate and submit to db after the user clicks "next", which is best way to do it...i have written the whole form in one page and want to save in db after the user clicks "next" but for this next button i have not writtrn type="submit" so how to pass data to controller
this the view , it display the form in multi step can any one give idea about how to save in db

```
<div class="container">
<div class="stepwizard">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel" >
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
            <p>Step 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
            <p>Step 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stepwizard-step">
            <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
            <p>Step 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form role="form">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="300" height="168" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 2</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <table class="table table-striped b-t b-light text-sm">
                         <tr>
                        <td> <a href="<?php echo site_url("user/register") ?>" > New User  ?? </a> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th>  Email </th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" /> </br> </br></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th>  Password </th>
                        <td> <input type="password" name="password" /> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <td> <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in" />  </td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3> Step 3</h3>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Finish!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use `AJAX`

Comment: @Rupam yes i m using AJAX but this data is not passed to controller

Answer (score 2):

Hi better you try this jquery steps plugins i can help you to solve your problem its validate first then  going to next step and at the end submit full form with all data. check example

http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Comment: the requirement is before going to next step data need to be save in db

Comment: all data saving in same table or every step has different table, if its saving in same table then submit it at the end, even if it is saving in different tables on each steps submit full form at the end and you know which step fields saved which table.

Comment: every step has differnet table and save those fields in db in every step

Comment: its really simple check the code example of steps its checking form validation onStepChanging method, if you have 3 forms on 3 steps create three different form validations, when validation true submit ajax form on that step return true and move next.

Comment: check this example of submit form with validation which will do more work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597739/jquery-validation-plugin-with-ajax-submit-handler-not-working